# How to reveal stacked ybar one symbolic x coord at a time in beamer

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, pgfplots

Hi I'm trying to make a stacked ybar plot in pgfplots + beamer, and reveal each stacked ybar one element at a time. So for my example here:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
       \begin{axis}[
           ybar stacked,
           width  = 0.9\columnwidth,
           height = 0.9\textheight,
           major x tick style = transparent,
           bar width=25pt,
           axis x line*=bottom,
           axis y line*=left,
           ymajorgrids = true,
           tick label style={/pgf/number format/assume math mode=true},
           ylabel = {Proportion $\%$},
           symbolic x coords={A, B, C},
           xtick = data,
           extra x tick style={grid=none},
           ymin=0,
           ymax=100,
           scaled y ticks = false,
           enlarge x limits=0.2,
           legend cell align=left,
           legend style={
                   draw=none,
                   at={(1.1,1.0)},
                   anchor=north,
                   font=\tiny
                   },
           nodes near coords,
           nodes near coords style={font=\tiny, text=white,/pgf/number format/assume math mode}   
       ]
           \addplot+[ybar]
               coordinates {(A, 31.4) (B, 35.8) (C, 27.1)};

           \addplot+[ybar]
               coordinates {(A, 22.7) (B, 31.2) (C, 14.1)};

           \addplot+[ybar]
               coordinates {(A, 3.8) (B, 3.9) (C, 3.7)};
            
           \addplot+[ybar]
               coordinates {(A, 8.9) (B, 0.0) (C, 17.7)};
            
           \addplot+[ybar]
               coordinates {(A, 9.3) (B, 0.0) (C, 18.4)};
               
            \addplot+[ybar]
               coordinates {(A, 23.8) (B, 28.9) (C, 18.9)};

           \legend{label1, label2, label3, label4, label5, label6}
       \end{axis}
   \end{tikzpicture}
```

I want the following bar chart, but with gradual reveal in beamer -- as in reveal ybar A first, then B, then C.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could cover up the bars on earlier overlays:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
         \begin{axis}[
             ybar stacked,
             width  = 0.9\columnwidth,
             height = 0.9\textheight,
             major x tick style = transparent,
             bar width=25pt,
             axis x line*=bottom,
             axis y line*=left,
%             ymajorgrids = true,
             tick label style={/pgf/number format/assume math mode=true},
             ylabel = {Proportion $\%$},
             symbolic x coords={A, B, C},
             xtick = data,
             extra x tick style={grid=none},
             ymin=0,
             ymax=100,
             scaled y ticks = false,
             enlarge x limits=0.2,
             legend cell align=left,
             legend style={
                     draw=none,
                     at={(1.1,1.0)},
                     anchor=north,
                     font=\tiny
                     },
             nodes near coords,
             nodes near coords style={font=\tiny, text=white,/pgf/number format/assume math mode},
%             at end bar={\pause}   
         ]
             \addplot+[ybar]
                 coordinates {(A, 31.4) (B, 35.8) (C, 27.1)};
  
             \addplot+[ybar]
                 coordinates {(A, 22.7) (B, 31.2) (C, 14.1)};
  
             \addplot+[ybar]
                 coordinates {(A, 3.8) (B, 3.9) (C, 3.7)};
              
             \addplot+[ybar]
                 coordinates {(A, 8.9) (B, 0.0) (C, 17.7)};
              
             \addplot+[ybar]
                 coordinates {(A, 9.3) (B, 0.0) (C, 18.4)};
                 
              \addplot+[ybar]
                 coordinates {(A, 23.8) (B, 28.9) (C, 18.9)};

             \legend{label1, label2, label3, label4, label5, label6}
         \end{axis}
         \begin{scope}[overlay]
           \fill<1>[white] (0.65,0.01) rectangle ++(1,10);
           \fill<1-2>[white] (3.6,0.01) rectangle ++(1,10);
           \fill<1-3>[white] (6.5,0.01) rectangle ++(1,10);
         \end{scope}
     \end{tikzpicture}
     \pause[4]
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```

[image]